# How do I set the login info for SQL Server 2008 in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, connection-string

Okay I'm still learning the ropes with the Entity Framework and I came across one more small issue.

When I create my Entity Model from the SQL Server 2008 database it warns me about saving the login information in the connection string in the config file. Initially I wasn't concerned about that so I just left it in there, but now I want to start thinking about deployment. So if I follow that advice and don't include the login information in the connection string, how else can I set that information later so that it can login to the database server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

- [Security Considerations (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760.aspx)
- [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx)
- [Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw.aspx)